# simulate CoMP (Coorinated Multipoint) scenario using Matlab

Tags: matlab

Im new to matlab, and needs to simulate a scenario, in which a mobile communicates with two base stations at the same time. I need to compare with the performance of communicating with just one base station. can someone please please tell me how to do this using Matlab?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spatial channel model (SCM) implementation:

[1] “Spatial channel model for multiple input multiple output (MIMO) simulations”, 3GPP TR 25.996 V6.1.0, Sep. 2003. [Online]. Available: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/25996.htm

Most of the code is in Matlab, but some computationally-intensive parts are also written in C to speed up the simulations.